# How to get values from this JSON String in Objective C, iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I wanted to parse a JSON String which looks like this.

There are more code in the Json String, i am pasting a sample here.

```
[

{  "Mainhd":"Select The Correct Adjective From The Given Options.",


  "Sub":

    [
        {
            "quetn":"Bill is two years ___ than Wanda.",
            "Answr":"1",  
            "optns":"1,2",                   
                "1":"younger",
                "2":"smaller"
        },
        {
            "quetn":"France is ___ European country.",
            "Answr":"2",
            "optns":"1,2",                   
                "1":"an",
                "2":"a"
        }]
}
]
```

For parsing the above JSON, I am doing like this in Objective C code.

```
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError* error;

    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData: jsonData //1
                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

    //NSLog(@"JSON : %@",json);
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"Error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    NSString *latestLoans = [json valueForKey:@"Mainhd"];
    NSLog(@"Mainhd: %@", latestLoans); //3

    NSString *sub = [json valueForKey:@"Sub"];
    NSLog(@"SUB: %@", sub); //3
```

While executing this code, I am getting this output.

```
SUB: (
        (

{
            1 = younger;
            2 = smaller;
            Answr = 1;
            optns = "1,2";
            quetn = "Bill is two years ___ than Wanda.";
        },
                {
            1 = an;
            2 = a;
            Answr = 2;
            optns = "1,2";
            quetn = "France is ___ European country.";
        },
                {
            1 = gorgeous;
            2 = gorgeousest;
            3 = gorgeouser;
            Answr = 1;
            optns = "1,2,3";
            quetn = "Arya is looking _______ in this dress.";
        }
```

)
    )

After that i want to get values from "SUB".

I am trying like this, but not working

```
 NSData *myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:sub];

    //NSData *jsonData2 = [sub dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData
                                                   options:0 error:&error];
      NSLog(@"ARR: %@", arr); //3
```

I am getting NULL.

Comment: Fixing your formatting may help you get a better response from people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's worth noting in the JSON you posted, that the value for sub is an array, so you would need to treat this as such and loop through it to get your values

```
    [

{  "Mainhd":"Select The Correct Adjective From The Given Options.",


  "Sub":

    [
        {
            "quetn":"Bill is two years ___ than Wanda.",
            "Answr":"1",  
            "optns":"1,2",                   
                "1":"younger",
                "2":"smaller"
        },
        {
            "quetn":"France is ___ European country.",
            "Answr":"2",
            "optns":"1,2",                   
                "1":"an",
                "2":"a"
        }]
}
]
```

So the following should point you in the right direction

```
          NSArray *subArray = [json valueForKey:@"Sub"];

        //loop array using each response as a dictionary

        for (NSDictionary *key in subArray){

//log the value to console

        NSLog (@"Value is %@", [key objectForKey:@"quetn");

    }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But When I am trying to print the length of subArray, I am getting 1, instead there are multiple values and the app is crashing at line inside the for loop.

Comment: :- I fixed it by doing like this>> subArray = [json valueForKey:@"Sub"][0]; taking first element.

Comment: It's difficult to advise as the log you have printed shows an array within an array, but the json example shows one array with 2 json objects in

Comment: :- thankyou for the help. I am new to this kind of programming.

Comment: No probs, I found this site really helpful when I started learning - good luck :)